# Spring Boot with purchased certificate gives error: Alias name [...] does not identify a key entry

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, spring-security, ssl-certificate

I bought an ssl certificate and got a `wildcard_certificate.cer` file and a `wildcard_certificate.p7b` file

I ran this command for import my certificate

```bash
keytool -import -alias arubaCert -file ./wildcard_certificate.cer -keystore ./wildcard_certificate.p12 -storepass myPassword
```

and then this command for set my certificate

```bash
keytool -importcert -file /root/server/static/keys/wildcard_certificate.cer -alias arubaCert -keystore /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts
```

but when I launch the server application, I get this error

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Alias name [arubaCert] does not identify a key entry
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getKeyManagers(SSLUtilBase.java:337) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.createSSLContext(SSLUtilBase.java:247) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:104) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar!/:na]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
```

How can I setup spring boot for https?

This is my properties file

```yaml
server.port=443
server.port.http=80
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-alias=arubaCert
server.ssl.key-password=myPassword
server.ssl.key-store=/root/server/static/keys/wildcard_certificate.p12
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
server.ssl.keyStoreType=PKCS12
server.ssl.keystore-password=myPassword
server.ssl.trust-certificate=/root/server/static/keys/wildcard_certificate.cer
trust.store=/root/server/static/keys/wildcard_certificate.p12
trust.store.password=myPassword
```

Answer (score 0):

You have only imported the certificate, not its corresponding private key.

Hence, it is not a key entry.

You need to add the private key that you used to generate the certificate signing request.

Comment: Ok, thank you @OrangeDog how can I import private key?

Comment: Actually, the p7b doesn't have the private key either. You presumably generated it yourself?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31132288/how-to-import-a-secret-key-into-key-store-by-keytool/31139339